# How to handle multiple overloads for dervied classes without requiring multiple changes to other files

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading

I wasn't sure how to word the title of this question, but here's my problem:

I am working on a game in C++ using the Entity Component System architecture. In this architecture, each game object is represented as a class:

```
class Object
```

A class is not much more than a container for components, which handle parts of the game object's logic.

```
class Component
```

Each component has an update function and event handlers for certain events. Each Event derives from a common base class, and each child object has it's own data fields to describe the Event. In my actual code, the base Event class has some attributes which all Events share.

```
class Event
{
};

class OnDeathEvent : public Event
{
public:
    int getKillerID() const
    {
        return 92341;
    }
};

class OnLevelEnterEvent : public Event
{
public:
    int getLevelEnteredID() const
    {
        return 100;
    }
};
```

Throughout the code, we send events to objects. Here's the main function I wrote to test my example code:

```
int main()
{
    Object obj;
    obj.sendEvent(OnLevelEnterEvent());
    obj.sendEvent(OnDeathEvent());
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

When an Object receives an Event, it delegates responsibility for that Event to it's components.

```
    for (auto& component : components)
    {
        component->handleEvent(e);
    }
```

I want to use function overloading for each Event type. Event handling functions then become very clear in their purpose.

```
void handleEvent(const OnLevelEnterEvent& e)
```

But doing this requires that the Object class AND the Component base Class both declare all the overloads for every Event type. Obviously, this is something we want to avoid because we would have to change multiple classes to add a new Event type to our game. Here is the rest of the example code:

```
class Component
{
public:

    virtual void handleEvent(const Event& e) {}
    virtual void handleEvent(const OnDeathEvent& e) {};
    virtual void handleEvent(const OnLevelEnterEvent& e) {};
};

class TestComponent : public Component
{
public:
    virtual void handleEvent(const OnDeathEvent& e)
    {
        std::cout << "You died. Your killer was: " << e.getKillerID() << std::endl;
    }
};

class AnotherComponent : public Component
{
public:
    virtual void handleEvent(const OnLevelEnterEvent& e) 
    {
        std::cout << "Level Entered with ID: " << e.getLevelEnteredID() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The object class:

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object() 
    {
        components.push_back(new TestComponent());
        components.push_back(new AnotherComponent());
    }


    void sendEvent(const Event& e)
    {
        for (auto& component : components)
        {
            component->handleEvent(e);
        }
    }

    void sendEvent(const OnDeathEvent& e)
    {
        for (auto& component : components)
        {
            component->handleEvent(e);
        }
    }

    void sendEvent(const OnLevelEnterEvent& e)
    {
        for (auto& component : components)
        {
            component->handleEvent(e);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Component*> components;
};
```

We want to be able to add a new Event type by inheriting from the Event class, without requiring changes to other files or creating new files (other than the new Event class). What would be an elegant way to structure our code?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want a single `sendEvent` method to, well, send any generic `Event` type. In this case you can create a `sendEvent(const Event* _event)` method as follows:

```
void sendEvent(const Event* _event) {
    for (auto& component : components) {
        component->handleEvent(_event);
    }
}
```

If you have implemented all derived classes of `Event` properly then polymorphism will take care of things allowing the correct `handleEvent` method to be called automatically depending upon the specific sub-class of `Event` (well, the pointer to it) that was passed to `sendEvent`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this wouldn't work. Eventually I would need to cast down since not all Event types share the same Event interface. And casting down is not much better than the code I already have

Answer (score 1):

Your component could register with the event.
When the child event is called it could notify its registered event listeners. You could define an interface and use interface inheritance.

Comment: I'm getting a pretty good idea of what you're saying, but I'm not entirely sure how that would look code-wise. A short example would be extremely helpful. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Works better with boost signals.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
class Event
{
public:
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (Event&) > T_notify_signal;
    virtual ~Event(){}
    void Register(const T_notify_signal::slot_type& c) {m_listeners.connect(c);}
    void NotifyListeners() {m_listeners(*this);}
    virtual std::string info() const = 0;
private:
    T_notify_signal m_listeners;
};
class OnDeathEvent : public Event
{
public:
    virtual ~OnDeathEvent(){}
    virtual std::string info() const { return "you are dead"; }
};
class OnLevelEnterEvent : public Event
{
public:
    virtual ~OnLevelEnterEvent(){}
    virtual std::string info() const { return "you are in a new area"; }
};
//----------------------------------------
class Component
{
public:
    virtual ~Component(){}
};
class TestComponent : public Component
{
public:
    TestComponent(){}
    virtual ~TestComponent(){}
    virtual void notifyLevelEnter(Event& e) {std::cout << "TestComponent::notifyLevelEnter(" << e.info() << ")" << std::endl;}
};
class AnotherComponent : public Component
{
public:
    AnotherComponent(){}
    virtual ~AnotherComponent(){}
    virtual void notifyDeath(Event& e) {std::cout << "AnotherComponent::notifyDeath(" << e.info() << ")" << std::endl;}
    virtual void notifyLevelEnter(Event& e) {std::cout << "AnotherComponent::notifyLevelEnter(" << e.info() << ")" << std::endl;}
};
//----------------------------------------
class Object
{
public:
    Object(){}
    ~Object(){}
    void addComponent( Component& component ) {m_components.push_back( &component );}
    void sendEvent(Event& e) {e.NotifyListeners();}
private:
    std::vector< Component* > m_components;
};
//----------------------------------------
int main()
{
   Object obj;

    // create components
    TestComponent tc;
    AnotherComponent ac;

    // create events
    OnDeathEvent      death_event;
    OnLevelEnterEvent level_enter_event;

    // hook up events to components
    death_event.Register( boost::bind( &AnotherComponent::notifyDeath, &ac, _1 ) );

    level_enter_event.Register( boost::bind( &TestComponent::notifyLevelEnter, &tc, _1 ) );
    level_enter_event.Register( boost::bind( &AnotherComponent::notifyLevelEnter, &ac, _1 ) );

    // add components to object
    obj.addComponent( ac );
    obj.addComponent( tc );

    // process game loop
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "obj.sendEvent(level_enter)" << std::endl;
        obj.sendEvent(level_enter_event);

        std::cout << "obj.sendEvent(death)" << std::endl;
        obj.sendEvent(death_event);

        std::cout << "obj.sendEvent(level_enter)" << std::endl;
        obj.sendEvent(level_enter_event);

        std::cout << "obj.sendEvent(level_enter)" << std::endl;
        obj.sendEvent(level_enter_event);

        std::cout << "obj.sendEvent(death)" << std::endl;
        obj.sendEvent(death_event);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```